# How to add a javascript code to the page at runtime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, recaptcha

I have the below script and noscript javascript codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfWqtgSAAAAAP1KwYFYGt0wDeJFtxznmqyRH_Q5">   </script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfWqtgSAAAAAP1KwYFYGt0wDeJFtxznmqyRH_Q5"
            height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <br>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">      </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
```

The above codes should be added to the page body only and only when a javascript variable is set from the server.

```
var shouldShow = true;

        $document.ready(function() {

            if (shouldShow) {

                // add
            } else {

                // don't add
            }
        });
```

How would that possible to add those scripts at runtime?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Page.RegisterStartupScript**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

```
if (shouldShow) {

        Page.RegisterStartupScript...
}
```

Comment: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
 var shouldShow = true;
 $document.ready(function() {
        if (shouldShow) {
           var newScript = document.createElement('script');
           newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
           newScript.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfWqtgSAAAAAP1KwYFYGt0wDeJFtxznmqyRH_Q5';
           document.body.appendChild(newScript);
        } else { ... }
```

And you can freely ignore noscript. As it is shown only if there is no JS enabled, but in that case it will not be added anyway.

But why not simply place it into some `asp:panel`, for instance, and set its visibility to true/false depending on if it should be shown or not? If some asp.net element has `elem.Visibility = false` it is not sent to browser, the same as all its content.